# Excel VBA - I think I am assigning a value to a cell but it isn't working

Tags: excel, vba

Line: Target("D12").Value = 10  'This doesn't put anything into the cell.
Trying to figure out the simplest first. Later I wish this to fill in 3 of the 4 columns, depending on which was entered into manually. This will have a few hundred rows. right now I am entering everything manually.  [image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False '<--| disable events handling
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler '<--| be sure to catch any error and enable events handling back


    Select Case Target.Column

            Case "3"
           'Me.Unprotect
            MsgBox Target.Address

           'MsgBox "Column" & Target.Cells.Column
           'boo = Target.Cells.Column + 1

           Target("D12").Value = 10
           MsgBox Target("D12").Value

            'Me.Protect

    End Select
ErrorHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the error handler and see where the throw is.  I suspect it's when `Target` does not contain `"D12"`...

Comment: What cell do you want to write in?

Comment: remove the `"` around the `3`.  `Target.Column` returns a long not a string.

Comment: `Target("D12").Value` = 10 should probably  be `Me.Range("D12")`  Would help to expalin exactly what you want to do here

Comment: @ScottCraner The `Select` will permissively cast to the target data type. It's still stylistically poor though.

Comment: Oh yah, Target is any row in column 3 that i clicked on to see if the case was working. I just realized that I am referencing the cell wrong that I want to assign to.

Comment: @Comintern interesting, so it is different than `IF`?  Because I though that in vba `3<>"3"`.  Learn me somtin' new.

Comment: Thank you all. I used to be access vba person. I remember very little of it and I know almost nothing about the excel object. Would rather spend all day figuring this out though rather than entering a few hundred rows into 4 columns manually. Stubborn

Comment: @ScottCraner It should work pretty much the same way in any expression - basically coercing each side of the comparison operator to a common type. I wrote up the rules on Doc a couple years ago, but I'm presuming that's long gone.

Comment: Ok so I shouldn't be mixing the " " for string with a number data type.